# MySQL UNION not working

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting a mysql union but nothing is returned?  Below is an example.  In total there is 16 select queries

```
$url_array = array(
   "euro-gbp","euro-aud","euro-usd",
   "euro-jpy","gbp-jpy","euro-cad",
   "usd-cad","usd-jpy","cad-jpy",
   "gbp-usd","aud-usd","gbp-cad",
   "aud-cad","aud-jpy","aud-nzd",
   "euro-nzd","gbp-aud","gbp-nzd",
   "nzd-usd","nzd-cad","nzd-jpy");

foreach($url_array as $urls) {
   $sql[]= "SELECT * 
     FROM `data_analysis_child` 
     WHERE type='".$urls."' 
     ORDER BY id DESC 
     LIMIT 2";

}

$sql = implode(" UNION ",$sql);
```

The sql result

```
SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='euro-gbp' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='euro-aud' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='euro-usd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='euro-jpy' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='gbp-jpy' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='euro-cad' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='usd-cad' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='usd-jpy' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='cad-jpy' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='gbp-usd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='aud-usd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='gbp-cad' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='aud-cad' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='aud-jpy' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='aud-nzd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='euro-nzd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='gbp-aud' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='gbp-nzd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='nzd-usd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='nzd-cad' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 UNION SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='nzd-jpy' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

How do i solve?  Is there a better way to restructure this query?

Comment: if nothing is returned then you have no records with type matching your where clause criteria. Run some of the queries  without the union do you get results then?  it appears you want the two newest records for each type defined.  is that correct?  If so you may be able to simulate a rowNumber() using user variables and write just 1 query w/ a sub query to get results.  Are you sure type doesn't have spaces or other characters?  does a single query return 2 records?

Comment: Yes, when i run the queries separately i get results

Comment: Check edit..  This is how i build the query.

Comment: Checking for errors might be advisable - particularly if you are creating a very large query.

Comment: Read the documentation of [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). The answer is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need  order by and limit for each select you should use ()  around each select

```
  foreach($url_array as $urls) {
        $sql[]= " (  SELECT * FROM `data_analysis_child` WHERE type='".$urls."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2  )";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Orderby matters when limit is used.

Comment: @xQbert  correct  .. (was a refuse)    .. answer updated  .. many thanks for suggestion

Comment: @scasisEdge your update seems off ... order by id desc limit 2 should that = be union?

Comment: @xQbert  = removed

Answer (score 1):

Just a little addition to do that. If you are getting ZERO results then use UNION ALL instead of only UNION. Actually duplicate records are avoided in UNION but with UNION ALL you will get everything that a query is returning. give it a try !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT @rank := if (@last_type=type, @rank+1, 1) as type_rank, *
  FROM data_analysis_child
  WHERE type IN ('euro-gbp', 'euro-aud', 'euro-usd'....)
  ORDER BY id DESC
)
WHERE type_rank<=2;
```

But the performance will suck.

Depending on how the indexes are configured and assuming that your id column is unique this might be better:

```
SELECT 'first', dac1.*
FROM data_analysis_child dac1
WHERE dac1.id IN (
   SELECT MAX(dac2.id)
   FROM data_analysis_child dac2
   WHERE dac2.type IN ('euro-gbp', 'euro-aud', 'euro-usd'....)
   GROUP BY dac2.type
)
UNION
SELECT 'second', dac3.*
FROM data_analysis_child dac3
WHERE dac3.id IN (
   SELECT MAX(dac4.id)
   FROM data_analysis_child dac4
   WHERE dac4.type IN ('euro-gbp', 'euro-aud', 'euro-usd'....)
   AND dac4.id NOT IN (
      SELECT MAX(dac5.id)
      FROM data_analysis_child dac5
      WHERE dac5.type IN ('euro-gbp', 'euro-aud', 'euro-usd'....)
      GROUP BY dac5.type
   ) 
   GROUP BY dac4.type
)
```

But it does not scale well to getting the top N values for each type.

A better solution would be to to flag the state of the first or second rank as an attribute on the record and filter directly.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) clearly explains:

> To apply `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` to an individual `SELECT`, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```

It also says:

> **Note**
>
> Previous versions of MySQL may permit such statements without parentheses. In MySQL 5.7, the requirement for parentheses is enforced.

If you are using MySQL 5.7 or newer, the code doesn't return anything because the query doesn't run. You should check the type of the returned value (the query functions return `FALSE` when the query is invalid) and the error message.